# http response and response.redirect simultameously in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, http-post, httpresponse, response.redirect

I am having an asp page(Sendxml.asp) which post an xml to another asp page (Receivexml.asp). On ReceiveXML.asp, I process the xml and send back the http response to SendXML.asp page and this works fine.

Now i have a situation where I have to send back the http response from ReceiveXML.asp to SendXML.asp but also i have to redirect the user to another url (page) from ReceiveXML.asp page.

Could any one please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Are you posting the XML in the browser or in the server code?

Comment: It is server code written in classic asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a redirect in `ReceiveXML.asp` as that page is only returning data to `SendXML.asp`.

You can only return one response for each request, and a redirect is also a form of response. Also, even if you return a redirect from `ReceiveXML.asp` that would only affect what is returned to `SendXML.asp`, it doesn't affect what `SendXML.asp` returns to the browser.

To redirect the user you have to do that in `SendXML.asp`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, you are correct here like in response to sendxml.asp I will send the url also in response to sendxml.asp and then redirect the user from sendxml.asp, but i have a limitation over here I can not make any code changes in sendxml.asp. So If you can help us in identifying different solution it will be a great help.

Comment: Perhaps you can wrap it all in another page, i.e. request from `SendXML.asp` as if the browser did it, and then redirect.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to convey.

Comment: @SalilGupta: I was thinking that you could make a new page, say `Send.asp`, that you would use instead of `SendXML.asp`. It would make a request to `SendXML.asp`, and when it got the response back it would do a redirect instead of sending the response back to the server.